# If $\lim_{x\to n}f(x) = 0$ and $f(n)=0$, does $\lim_{x\to n}\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)} = 1$ always?

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{x\to n}f(x) = 0$ and $f(n)=0$, does $\lim_{x\to n}\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)} = 1$ always?

I have been playing around with some graphs on desmos and there's always the indication that the limit equals $1$. I know that $\sin x$ becomes very linear, is there any function with the potential to "un-linearize" it?

Answer (score 3):

It is always true if $f(n) \neq 0$ in a punctured neighborhood of $x=n$ otherwise we can't take the limit.

Comment: (+1) for the correct answer.

Comment: @MarkViola Sometimes I also need to be wrong to learn something new form you! Much appreciate. Thanks, Bye!

Comment: @MarkViola It seems I'm wrong :) ...at least for some other user.

Comment: @user  I only downvoted one answer here, and it was not yours.  TheSilverDoe is spreading false rumors.  Cheers! :)

Comment: You were the only one being snarky here, @TheSilverDoe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that:

> $\exists \delta' > 0$ such that if $|x - n| < \delta'$, then $|f(x)| > 0$.

---

Since $f(n) = \lim_{x\to n}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y} = 1$, we know that:

> $\forall \varepsilon_1 > 0$, $\exists \delta_1 > 0$ such that if $|x - n| < \delta_1$, then $|f(x)| < \varepsilon_1$
>
> $\forall \varepsilon_2 > 0$, $\exists \delta_2 > 0$ such that if $0 < |y| < \delta_2$, then $|\frac{\sin y}{y} - 1| < \varepsilon_2$

Now given any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $\delta > 0$ be $\min({\delta', \delta_1})$, where:

- $\delta_1$ corresponds to taking $\varepsilon_1 = \delta_2$
- $\delta_2$ corresponds to taking $\varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon$

Then observe that if $0 < |x - n| < \delta$, then:

- We know that $|x - n| < \delta \leq \delta'$, so $|f(x)| > 0$.
- We know that $|x - n| < \delta \leq \delta_1$, so $|f(x)| < \varepsilon_1 = \delta_2$.
- We know that $0 < |f(x)| < \delta_2$, so $|\frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)} - 1| < \varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

This is true, just by composition of limits. Indeed,
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow n} f(x)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}=1$$

so composing the two limits, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow n} \frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}=1$$

Comment: No problem, since the function $x \mapsto \sin(x)/x$ is defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Not when $x= 0$.  Responding to your last comment, @TheSilver

Comment: Letting the value at $x=0$ be $1$, it is well-defined and continuous (even analytic). So I guess we can consider that the limit is well-defined even if $f$ vanishes in every neighbourhood of $n$.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

Let $ \epsilon>0$.
we know that
$$\lim_{X\to 0,\ne}\frac{\sin(X)}{X}=1$$

Thus
$\exists \eta>0$ such that

$$\color{red}{0<}|X|<\eta \implies |\frac{\sin(X)}{X}-1|<\epsilon$$

But
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$
then
$\exists \alpha>0 $ such that
$$|x|<\alpha \implies |f(x)|<\eta$$

The red condition $ \color{red}{0<|f(x)|}$ is not always satisfied to insure the existence of $\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}$.

Your conclusion will be correct if you put$$\frac{\sin(0)}{0}=1$$

Comment: Will you please stop posting an "answer" and then editing your your answer four  times in four minutes?

Comment: I am using a small mobile and old as i am it is not so easy.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: Ok. I will stop using it for 14 days.